# Unit Test a ng-select dropdown(Angular, Jasmine)

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have to test the options from a ng-select. For that I created a mock for the option in the unit test and I test it in async. optionsForSelect(from the html) comes from an @Input(). How can I do this? Thank you very much! I will appreciate any help.

```js
describe('Component', () => {
    let component: Component;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [Component],
            imports: [NgSelectModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule],
            providers: [
            { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: {} }]
        })
            .overrideComponent(Component, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: FormBuilder }
                    ]
                }
            })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should have correct values in options dropdown', async(() => {
        const mockControl = { option: "optionOne", translation: "label.translated"};
        component.form = buildForm();
        let select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.select-field')).nativeElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.form.controls['controlTwo'] = new FormControl(mockControl);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            let text = select.options[1].label;
            expect(text).toBe('optionOne');
        });
    }))

})

function buildForm() {
    const formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
    return formBuilder.group({
        controlOne: [{ value: null, disabled: false }, Validators.required],
        controlTwo: [{ value: null, disabled: false }],
        ...
    });
}
```

```html
 <ng-select class="select-field" [searchable]="false" [clearable]="false"
                formControlName="controlTwo">
                <ng-option *ngFor="let option of optionsForSelect"
                  [value]="option.option">
                  {{ option.translation | translate }}
                </ng-option>
 </ng-select>
```